# Javascript execute statement after fetch statements are complete

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous, promise, fetch

Here i am converting `blob urls` present in array called `imgs[]` to `base64 data` and then pushing the base 64 data in an array called `imgsPost[]`.
After all base64 data is pushed into an array i want to use that array in a function.

```
let imgsPost = [];
let imgs = ["bloburl1", "bloburl2", "bloburl3", "bloburl4"];
for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    fetch(imgs[i].src)
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
            return res.blob();
        })
        .then(data => {
            let tempBlob = data;
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(tempBlob);
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                let base64data = reader.result;
                imgsPost.push(base64data);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })
}
        //After all execution
        foo($imgsPost);
```

Right now the function executes first with an empty array. All other code is functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronism issue. You're telling 4 times to execute some code **after** the results have arrived, then you execute `foo($imgsPost);` **before** the results have arrived.

Solution that uses `Promise.all`:

```js
const imgs = [
    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ac4d13d84719bf7f11cfd9ba7e0b15b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f1f3cf96ee354f414ec58c2824f80938?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'
];

const promises = imgs.map(img => fetch(img)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
        return res.blob();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(data);
        return new Promise(resolve => reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader));
    })
    .then(({ result }) => result)
);

const foo = console.log;

Promise.all(promises).then(foo).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error: ', error);
});
```

You could also use `async`/`await` syntax which provides really useful syntaxic sugar over  promises and makes the code look like it's synchronous.

Comment: I tested it before posting, are you sure that the array contains valid URLs?

Comment: @SalilMittal there was a little mistake in the code: `img.src` instead of just `img`. I fixed it and published it as runnable code. Try it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `foo($imgsPost)` is synchronous and is being called before the async fetch requests have been completed. You can try to create a bunch of fetch requests and put them into an array and use `Promise.all()` to await the completion of all requests, before calling `foo()`.

I'm not sure if it's a typo or just an example but there is no `.src` property in your imgs array.

```
const imgs = ["bloburl1", "bloburl2", "bloburl3", "bloburl4"];
const fetchRequests = imgs.map(img => {
    return fetch(img.src)
              .then(res => {
                 if (!res.ok) {
                    throw Error(res.statusText);
                 }
                 return res.blob();
                })
               .then(data => {
                  let tempBlob = data;
                  let reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.readAsDataURL(tempBlob);
                  reader.onloadend = function () {
                  return reader.result;            
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            })
        }

   Promise.all(fetchRequests).then(allRes => foo(allRes))
```

Comment: That won't work because the result of the onloadend callback will never be retrieved

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did some bad copy and pasting. But glad the above answer got it sorted for you